# Pyzbar works not good with Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, zbar

I want to decode a QR-Code on Ubuntu/Linux. I installed the libary and started the Code. The result is an empty array. On my windows device the result is the correct code data. Can anyone try the Code on there linux device and if it works tell me the way to install the pyzbar libary correct, i think there is the problem. If you have any other ideas, please let me know.
Image(Code)=https://www.directupload.net/file/d/5519/tsv8hg76_jpg.htm

I tried the Code on windows and it works perfectly fine.
On ubuntu i installed the libary like this https://pypi.org/project/pyzbar/

import cv2

import pyzbar.pyzbar as pyzbar

Image = cv2.imread("wfunktioniert.jpg",0)

decodedObjects = pyzbar.decode(Image)
print(decodedObjects)

print("Ende")

No errors, just no correct result

Answer (score 0):

I encounter this problem today. One picture decoded fine on my MAC but not decoded on my ubuntu server.

I finally find out that my ubuntu server RAM is too small, it's only 2G, but my MAC has 16G. And I created a VM with 4G RAM, test the picture again with pyzbar, it decoded successfully.

So I think you can try to add more RAM to your machine.

Or you can try zxing. I found out that zxing decoded the picture with 2G RAM.

Answer (score -1):

You can use
from pyzbar import pyzbar to import the module
And to decode
barcode=pyzbar.decode(image)

[Zbar opencv link](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/05/21/an-opencv-barcode-and-qr-code-scanner-with-zbar/)

Follow the link.

Comment: Hi there and welcome to SO. Can you provide more context for how the info in the link will help the OP? It's best practice here to include a full answer rather than direct people elsewhere, because links present security risks and they break over time, making your answer useless for future users.

Comment: Thank you Manjeet, I already tried the link and the perfect Codes like the one in the link are no problem for the module but not as perfect codes like the one i uploaded in the questions are not working on linux but on windows